# Hide the keyboard after clicking on the EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I'm using Date and Time Picker to handle the meeting date field, so there is no need for the keyboard. How can I prevent the keyboard from showing after clicking on the field?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZWZ8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="text|date"/>
```

And add click listener to this view in code

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //show date picker
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way of programatically hiding the keyboard.

Go in xml and add the following attribute `android:focusable="false"`

E.g

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time_date_et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/prompt_light"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

The above attribute ensures that the keyboard won't appear!

Answer (score 0):

```
val activity: Activity = this //if you are in the Activity
val imm = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            var view = activity.currentFocus
            if (view == null) {
                view = View(activity)
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
```

this piece of code should hide your virtual keyboard. Just put it in a method and call. :)